# 2 node cluster (active-passive) with Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, cluster, high-availability, windows-server-2016, virtual-ip

I'd like to create a **2 node cluster** with 2 servers with **Windows Server 2016** standard.
My cluster should be in active-passive configuration

- without shared storage (SAN, iSCSI, etc.)
- without active directory

I'd like to get a virtual IP passed between the two nodes and then configure services that switch from one node to the other depending on who's active.

I've configured something similar on Centos with the HA stack (pacemaker, corosync [link](http://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/ch05.html))

Is is possible to do something like this on Windows Server 2016?

Thank you

Comment: Microsoft refer to this as failover clustering. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/blob/master/WindowsServerDocs/failover-clustering/failover-clustering-overview.md

Answer (score 5):

What are you looking for is the Workgroup WSFC (Windows Server Failover Cluster):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clustering/2015/08/17/workgroup-and-multi-domain-clusters-in-windows-server-2016/

For the storage, I would recommend referring to StarWind free:

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san

It takes the local disks and simply mirror them between the servers setting up an HA storage for the cluster. In addition, you get a ton of features and all that stuff.

Btw, its services can be installed directly on the physical nodes eliminating an extra overhead of passing though a large number of the abstract layers. IMHO, its one of the most transparent ways for building up a 2 node cluster.

Comment: I've tried to follow the tutorial for Workgroup WSFC, but it didn't work. "Each cluster node needs to have a primary DNS suffix" I've configured the DNS suffix but the nodes  could not see each other.